# How can I attach lumber for a shelf so that screws are not seen?

Tags: wood, screws, joints

So I'm making a simple shelf like the one in the picture.  I asked the home depot guy and the guy told me to use regular screws and then use filling to cover up the holes, something I already knew.

I asked if there's a way to attach them so that the screws couldn't be seen, but he didn't know.

So how can I attach these two pieces is wood so that the screws cannot be seen from the top?

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that a 2x12 is not actually 2 by 12 inches, it's more like 1.5 by 11.5.

Comment: 11-1/4, actually.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: Don't use screws.** Old-school cabinet makers used dowels and glue. It's not difficult, but you'll want to read up on alignment techniques. Joints are very strong.

[image]

<sub>[image source](http://www.renovation-headquarters.com/cabinets-base-cabinets-4.html)</sub>

**Option 2: Use pocket screws.** They're what modern cabinet makers use. They're probably cost- and effort-prohibitive in your case, though, since they require special tools (or advanced technique) and your work space is very tight.

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://woodgears.ca/joint_strength/index.html)</sub>

**Option 3: Use long screws from the bottom.** If your dimensions are correct, and your top panel really is 2 inches thick, you have enough material to counterbore from below and run the screws in that way.

[image]

<sub>[image source](https://www.canadianwoodworking.com/get-more/common-wood-screw)</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm thinking of using dowels and glue. Is there a link you can share that will show me how to install the dowels and align them correctly?

Comment: It's a very common technique and you should have no trouble finding resources. I've never researched the topic since I learned it far before the internet. [Here's a start](https://www.wonkeedonkeetools.co.uk/dowels/how-do-you-use-dowels-to-make-wooden-joints/)

Comment: Option 1a.  Use a biscuit jointer.  If you already have a biscuit jointer, or would welcome an opportunity to buy one, they are very easy, and I find them much easier to align.